# Python Regular expression - Substitution

Tags: python, regex

I have written a python code :

```
import re

url = "www.google.com";
line = "../../asyouwish.html"

num = re.sub(r'(\.\.\/)*', url, line)
print ("Final : ", num)
```

My intention is to replace ../ (any number  of times) with the url value provided.
However I am not getting correct output. My desired output is "www.google.com/asyouwish.html".

What I get is :

```
Final :  www.google.comawww.google.comswww.google.comywww.google.comowww.google.
comuwww.google.comwwww.google.comiwww.google.comswww.google.comhwww.google.com.w
ww.google.comhwww.google.comtwww.google.commwww.google.comlwww.google.com
```

Can anyone help me as where I went wrong !!!
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`*` means 0-or-more occurrences. `+` means 1-or-more. You want a match to have at least 1 occurrence of `../`. So change the `*` to `+`:

```
import re

url = "www.google.com/"
line = "../../asyouwish.html"

num = re.sub(r'([.]{2}/)+', url, line)
print ("Final : ", num)
```

yields

```
('Final : ', 'www.google.com/asyouwish.html')
```

Since the `re.sub` will remove 1-or-more `'../'`, you'll need to add a forward-slash after `url`. Above, I've added the forward-slash to `url` itself. If `url` comes without the forward-slash, you can (as an alternative) add it with

```
num = re.sub(r'([.]{2}/)+', url+'/', line)
```

---

When you match on 0-or-more occurrences, `r'([.]{2}/)*'`, each and every location *between* the characters in `line` matches the pattern, so you get a substitution at each interstice.

```
In [9]: x = 'www.google.comawww.google.comswww.google.comywww.google.comowww.google.comuwww.google.comwwww.google.comiwww.google.comswww.google.comhwww.google.com.www.google.comhwww.google.comtwww.google.commwww.google.comlwww.google.com'

In [13]: x.split('www.google.com')
Out[13]: ['', 'a', 's', 'y', 'o', 'u', 'w', 'i', 's', 'h', '.', 'h', 't', 'm', 'l', '']
```

Comment: Good answer, but I'd elaborate a bit why they get the described result.

Comment: using split to get the last element and then appending it to the url seems a better way than using `re`

Answer (score 0):

use something like

```
url = "www.google.com";
line = "../../asyouwish.html"
link_part = line.split("/")

final_url = url + "/" + link_part[-1]
```